# Correct usage of Theory in xUnit

Tags: .net, unit-testing, xunit

I've been reading about xunit and I'm a bit confused how to use Theory.

Lets say I have this test:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("")]
[InlineData("anything")]
public void AddItem_NoName_ThrowsNoNameException(string name)
{
    // Arrange.
    ItemService itemService = new ItemService();
    Item item = new Item();
    item.Name = name;

    // Act.
    Exception ex = Record.Exception(() => itemService.AddItem(item));

    // Assert.
    Assert.NotNull(ex);
    Assert.IsType<NoNameException>(ex);
}
```

And the method under test:

```
public void AddItem(Item item)
{
    if (item.Name == "")
        throw new NoNameException();
    _DAL.AddItem(item);
}
```

So this creates two unit tests: one passing an argument of empty string ("") and  one the word "anything". So the first one (the empty string) passes since we have code that checks if item.Name is empty string, throw exception. The second one however, fails, because Assert.NotNull(ex) in the unit test will be false. However, if you look at the AddItem method, the method is correctly coded so what I want to see is both tests pass.

Maybe I'm wrong in how I implemented by unit test but what I want to happen or what I think should happen in this case is that both test should pass since the method under test is correct (based on the rules). How do I do this?

**UPDATE:**

OK, I've managed to make this both pass by doing the code below. However, I think that is not correct, to have conditional assertion. Still need help.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("", false)]
[InlineData("anything", true)]
public void AddItem_NoName_ThrowsNoNameException(string name, isValid)
{
    // Arrange.
    ItemService itemService = new ItemService();
    Item item = new Item();
    item.Name = name;

    // Act.
    Exception ex = Record.Exception(() => itemService.AddItem(item));

    // Assert.
    if (!isValid)
    {
        Assert.NotNull(ex);
        Assert.IsType<NoNameException>(ex);
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.Null(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the documentation is unclear? http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop

Comment: @Daniel Mann: The case for their example is clear, but I don't think so in my case.

Comment: I agree with your statement about not having a conditional assertion.  This should be split into two individual tests.  The one to verify the exception is thrown for empty name, and one to verify the happy path.   You could add an additional case to your existing theory for when `name` is `null` as it should consist of the same test code as empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are two different test cases and should have individual tests written.  `Theory` should be used when the test code is the same.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("")]
[InlineData(null)] // will fail based on your impl, just used for example
public void AddItem_NoName_ThrowsNoNameException(string name)
{
    // Arrange
    ItemService itemService = new ItemService();
    Item item = new Item();
    item.Name = name;

    // Act & Assert
    Assert.Throws<NoNameException>(() => itemService.AddItem(item));
}


[Fact]
public void AddItem_WithName_DoesXYZ()
{
    // Arrange
    ItemService itemService = new ItemService();
    Item item = new Item();
    item.Name = "anything";

    // Act
    itemService.AddItem(item);

    // Assert
    # verify item was added to db 
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's what is confusing for me. In this link http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop, they said "Theories are tests which are only true for a particular set of data.". So I was thinking you can pass some wrong and right values in Theory (as in the example in that page). If that is the case, do we leave the wrong data test as not passing in our list of tests? What's the purpose of allowing wrong data to Theory?

Comment: I think that is just a misinterpretation.  You will want to use data in your theory cases that should pass.  I don't have a reason for passing wrong data, this I assume would cause a test to fail which kind of defeats the purpose.